# Small app to automatically download podcasts

Tags: software-rec, itunes, download, podcasts

Is there a small utility/app that will download podcasts automatically for me? I don't want to run iTunes all the time, since it takes up a lot of memory and I have an old laptop.

I just tried [Juice (previously iPodder)](http://juicereceiver.sourceforge.net/index.php), but it's a little buggy (can't import OPML file, directories seem not to load, etc).

Should I spend time getting Juice to work for me, or is there another (better) app?

It'd be sweet if the app integrates with iTunes (imports existing podcasts, saves to iTunes' podcast directory, etc).

Or is there a way to make iTunes operate with a small memory footprint just for this purpose?

Comment: "Or is there a way to make iTunes operate with a small memory footprint just for this purpose?" assuming iTunes is mostly idle in the background, the majority of its memory pages will be stored in the page file. That is: on your hard disk and not using up physical memory.

Comment: any of [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_podcatchers#Microsoft_Windows) work?

Answer (score 1):

gPodder supports importing iTunes subscriptions. It's also reasonably lightweight.

http://wiki.gpodder.org/wiki/User_Manual#Importing_subscriptions_from_iTunes

Comment: +1. It also supports importing OPML files.